# Perl script to split a file based on a pattern at a certain offset

Tags: text-processing, perl

I need your help to get an idea as to how to split a large file into small sub-files as said in the example below.

Criteria is we are looking at offset 30 (31st bytes to 2 bytes). If the offset contains 0A then the record should be copied to file A, if its 0B @ 32 then it should be copied to file B and if its a 0C then it should be copied to file C

Sample input file:

```
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110C11111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
```

Output file A:

```
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
```

Output File B:

```
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
```

Output File C:

```
1111111111111111111111111111110C11111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

For each line you can just use  `substr($line,30,2)` to get the two characters you want.  So something like

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open(my $file1,">file1");
open(my $file2,">file2");
open(my $file3,">file3");
while(<>)
{
  my $ch=substr($_,30,2);
     if ($ch eq '0A') { print $file1 $_; }
  elsif ($ch eq '0B') { print $file2 $_; }
  elsif ($ch eq '0C') { print $file3 $_; }
  else { print "Bad line skipped: $_"; }
}
```

We can see this in action:

```
$ cat input 
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110C11111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
$ ./script input 
$ cat file1
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
$ cat file2
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
$ cat file3
1111111111111111111111111111110C11111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne '
    $filename = substr($_,30,2); 
    open $fh{$filename}, ">", $filename unless exists $fh{$filename}; 
    print {$fh{$filename}} $_
' file

$ cat 0A
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110A111111111111111111111111111111

$ cat 0B
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110B111111111111111111

$ cat 0C
1111111111111111111111111111110C11111111111111111111111
```